# Enhanced Dynamic Content marketing cloud

Tags: salesforce

I'm trying to use the Enhanced Dynamic content, but when I create the content block, I don't get the option to load the file. Does anyone know why?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi there, could you post the code that you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You need to click on Upload to import the .csv file.

click: Create > Upload > Enhanced dynamic content

Thanks,